# Lenovo Y580 touchpad pointer runs away while trying to click

Tags: touchpad, lenovo

I've just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my Lenovo Y580. I don't have physically divided mouse buttons from my touchpad surface, so I can't manage with the issue just by clicking on physical buttons. The button surface is also touchable.

While "tapping" the touchpad in accordance to make a click my mouse pointer is moving so sensitively that sometimes when I like to close something or just press a small button (like "x" to close the window) I can't manage to do this because my pointer moves away from the button area. On Windows I think it works like that: when I tap the touchpad, pointer movement is like suspended so the clicking is precise. In Ubuntu it doesn't work that way. I've checked in mouse and touchpad settings and nothing helps from there.

How to make the mouse pointer not move while trying to click on a tiny button?

Answer (score 1):

To get the trackpad working correctly you need to use the terminal and enter in the below commands. Make sure you press enter after each command:

```
sudo -i 
echo "options psmouse proto=exps" > /etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.modprobe
reboot
```

Once the computer reboots your trackpad will be able to do left click and drag and right clicking